# Issue After URL Routing using URL Rewrite 2 Module of IIS

Tags: c#, asp.net, url-routing, httpexception, validate-request

**ASP.NET has detected data in the request that is potentially dangerous because it might include HTML markup or script.**

The above error is being thrown after I use URL Rewrite 2 Module of IIS for url routing. I know the cause of the error that one of my input parameters contains a invalid URL character (i.e. '<').

I am just wondering that this error was not thrown earlier when I am not using URL Rewriting Module. Also How can I elegantly handle this error without setting  **validateRequest** to **FALSE** as this is not recommended.My website is using asp.net 2.

Comment: try to encode the string (assuming a parameter) before forwarding [HttpUtility.UrlEncode](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4fkewx0t%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

Comment: @KraangPrime - thanks for your reply but the requirement is to store the string with character '<' in DB. My main concern is that why it is happening as it was not throwing this error earlier when the URL Rewriting was not used.

Comment: Encode to pass the string -- decode & use prepared statements to insert into database.